How to get accurate caller() in Mojolicious?
How do I get Mojolicious' stacktrace to reflect the physical source code ?
For example, when executing the below code:
/foo/bar/app.pl:

 1 #!/usr/bin/env perl
 2 use Mojolicious::Lite;
 3
 4 get '/' => sub {
 5   my $c = shift;
 6
 7   my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs, $wantarray,
 8     $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash) = caller(0);
 9
10   $c->render(text =>
11     'p=' . $package    . ',' .
12     'f=' . $filename   . ',' .
13     'l=' . $line       . ',' .
14     'm=' . $subroutine
15   );
16 };
17
18 app->start;

Actual:
# /foo/bar/app.pl daemon

p=Mojolicious,f=/usr/local/share/perl5/Mojolicious.pm,l=202,m=main::__ANON__

# morbo /foo/bar/app.pl

p=Mojolicious,f=/usr/local/share/perl5/Mojolicious.pm,l=202,m=Mojo::Server::Sandbox::b89e17a47746799cd9250564e1c58531::__ANON__

Expected:
f=/foo/bar/app.pl
l=7
m=main::__ANON__


You can use __LINE__ and __FILE__ instead.

You want information about the current sub, but caller primarily provides information about the caller of the current sub.
Well, the first three returned values are about the caller. Some if not all of the rest are about the called sub.

Solution 1
use feature qw( current_sub say );

use Sub::Util qw( subname );

sub f {
   say join "|", __PACKAGE__, __FILE__, __LINE__, subname( __SUB__ );
}

f();

main|a.pl|6|main::f


Solution 2
use feature qw( say );



sub f {
   say join "|", __PACKAGE__, __FILE__, __LINE__, ( caller( 0 ) )[ 3 ];
}

f();

main|a.pl|6|main::f


Solution 3
use feature qw( current_sub say );

sub self_info { ( caller( 0 ) )[ 0, 1, 2 ], ( caller( 1 ) )[ 3 ] }

sub f {
   say join "|", self_info();
}

f();

main|a.pl|6|main::f


Note that Sub::Util (and Sub::Name) provide the means of naming your anon subs.

Remember that you are merely defining an anonymous subroutine in app.pl. It's called from somewhere else, so you are getting the actual and true results. This is going to be the case for must sorts of callback programming.
I figure your example is just a demonstration, but you don't say what problem you are trying to solve.
If I'm trying to figure out what's going on and who is involved, I'd probably just log it:
 $c->app->log->trace( ... );

That log message can be any format you like and have any message you like. You can use the stuff @ikegami already showed.
